# is_quoted() method in Text::CSV perl module

Tags: perl, csv, perl-module

I may be missing something obvious, but I have a very simple perl script in which the is_quoted() method in the Text::CSV module is not working as expected. Here's the code:

```
# cat ./testcsv.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { quote_char => '"' } )
        or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

print "Text::CSV version = " . $csv->version() . "\n\n";

my $line = '"text field 111",222,"text field 333",444';

my $status  = $csv->parse($line);
if ($status)
  {
  my $column_idx = 0;
  my @fields = $csv->fields ();
  foreach my $field (@fields)
     {
     my $quoted = $csv->is_quoted ($column_idx);
     $column_idx++;
     print "field #$column_idx: '$field'; quoted = " . ($quoted ? "YES\n" : "NO\n");
     }
  }
```

And here's what I get when I run the script:

```
    # perl -v  | grep "is perl"
    This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for PA-RISC2.0
    # ./testcsv.pl
    Text::CSV version = 1.29

    field #1: 'text field 111'; quoted = NO
    field #2: '222'; quoted = NO
    field #3: 'text field 333'; quoted = NO
    field #4: '444'; quoted = NO
    #
```

As we can see, the parse() method is correctly separating the original string into fields, so I know that Text::CSV is installed and working correctly. It was my understanding from reading the [documentation for Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) that the is_quoted() method is supposed to return a true value if the data in the indicated column is enclosed in quote_char quotes. Therefore I was expecting to see 'YES' after fields 1 & 3, as they're clearly quoted in the initialization for the $line variable. But this is not happening.

Am I doing something wrong, or is Text::CSV broken?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify `keep_meta_info => 1`.

---

By the way, I dislike having two iterators, so I'd iterate over the indexes.

```
my @fields = $csv->fields();
for my $column_idx (0..$#fields) {
   my $field = $fields[$column_idx];
   ...
}
```

Comment: Duh. Thanks. That's the correct answer. Thanks very much for answering so quickly, and sorry for the waste of bandwidth! (I would vote you up but don't have sufficient reputation to do so.)

Comment: The answer wasn't obvious to me either. It should be mentioned in the docs for `is_quoted`. I looked up the test file for it, though I later noticed the example in the Synopsis also uses `keep_meta_info`.

Comment: I agree with your comment about using only one iterator; in that case, however, the iterator range would be: `(0..$#fields - 1)`

Comment: @barush - No, ikegami is correct. $#fields returns the last index of, not the # of elements in, the array.

Comment: @barush, `0..$#fields` or `0..@fields-1`, but no, not `0..$#fields-1`

Comment: Regarding the non-obvious answer (`keep_meta_info =>1`), is there some formal mechanism by which one might request that the Text::CSV module's authors update the documentation for the `is_quoted()` method (and for any others affected by `keep_meta_info`)?

Comment: Go to the [distro](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV/) on CPAN and click "View/Report bugs"